# Is it possible to relay an RTP stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have a use case where I have camera (on a drone, with a raspberry pi) behind a NAT, a VPS Server with a public IP, and a client behind a NAT where I want to display the video.

The client is running a software called QGroundcontroll which listens for an RTP stream on a local UDP port, usually 5000.

If I run the client on a VPN so it gets a public IP I can get the video across, but the VPN is introducing too much lag. I can demonstrate that by running the following on my drone:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264 -f rtp udp://my-client-vpn-fixed-ip:5000
```

Which will give me a nice (but slightly distorted) test picture.

Another test I have done is to run the testsrc directly on my client like so, also successfully:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264 -f rtp udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

So now I have worked out this idea about relaying the rtp stream via my VPS.

This is what I have tried:

On the drone (behind NAT):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264 -f rtp udp://my-virtual-private-server-fixed-ip:5600
```

On the VPS (Fixed IP, running Debian, thus `avconv`):

```
avconv -i udp://127.0.0.1:5600 -map 0:0 -c copy -f rtp udp://127.0.0.1:5500
```

On the client (My Mac, behind NAT):

```
ffmpeg -i udp://my-virtual-private-server-fixed-ip:5500 -map 0:0 -c copy -f rtp udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

It seems like neither `avconv` nor `ffmpeg` is able to detect or connect to an RTP stream using `-i udp://adress:port`. Is it supposed to be possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not possible with avconv or ffmpeg (AFAIK) as it would require them to create a UDP socket and listen on it for the incoming data. You need a purpose built UDP relay. Your best option might be to setup a VPN via your VPS, so your drone can send the stream directly to the *private* IP of your client.